# Android Development android.view.InflateException Error Inflating Class

Tags: android

So I'm having a weird error on my rudimentary music app for college that was working perfect about half an hour ago and now it's deciding to throw this error when I click an element of my listView.

Here's my Second Activity

```
package com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SongsActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.songs);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        String songName = b.getString("Name");
        String songArtist = b.getString("Artist");
        String songAddress = b.getString("Address");

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        tv1.setText(songName);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        tv2.setText(songArtist);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        tv3.setText(songAddress);

        returnClick();
        youTube();
    }

    private void returnClick()
    {
        Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void youTube()
    {
        Button videoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton);
        videoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
           public void onClick(View v)
            {
                TextView url = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Address);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse((String) url.getText())));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the XML for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".SongsActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View Video"
        android:id="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/returnButton"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share"
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/returnButton"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Return"
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/Artist"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/Address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Artist"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone have any ideas? Annoyingly enough it's due tomorrow.

Error is coming from "this.setContentView(R.layout.songs);

Here's the logcat:

```
12-16 22:36:06.226  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 12% free 7793K/8764K, paused 10ms, total 11ms
12-16 22:36:06.261  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 37.766MB for 30720016-byte allocation
12-16 22:36:06.331  14297-14306/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 37791K/38768K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
12-16 22:36:06.426  14297-14301/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 37790K/38768K, paused 2ms+66ms, total 95ms
12-16 22:36:06.631  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-16 22:36:06.746  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-16 22:36:06.751  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-16 22:36:06.756  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-16 22:36:06.756  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
12-16 22:36:06.756  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
12-16 22:36:06.796  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-16 22:36:15.896  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
12-16 22:36:15.896  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer E/ActivityThread﹕ Pause GC
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:15.971  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 3% free 41993K/42972K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
12-16 22:36:15.971  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 36864016-byte allocation
12-16 22:36:15.991  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 3% free 41983K/42972K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
12-16 22:36:15.991  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42024d08 self=0x42013850
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=14297 nice=-11 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074258260
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 1661205092 98975660 534 ) utm=78 stm=88 core=3
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3708)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3638)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:474)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:16)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:15.996  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 12-16 22:36:15.996 14297:14297 D/skia     ]
    --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
12-16 22:36:16.001  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-16 22:36:16.001  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42023c08)
12-16 22:36:16.001  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer, PID: 14297
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer.SongsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
            at com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
            at com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3708)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3638)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:474)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
            at com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 22:36:17.836  14297-14297/com.example.davidcoleman.musicplayer I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 14297 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate where in your code the exception is coming from.

Comment: Added all of that now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

You probably use some huge jpg or have many memory leaks. 
To fix earlier try to use pngs instead.
To fix leaks, well, don't leak activities ;) Its quite a complicated issue discussed in many post here, on stack.

Comment: You absolute champion, sound!